# Elements positioning in a custom block

Tags: block-editor

I've started to learn the development of custom blocks of the block editor. How can I make a block with two columns with a h1 tag in the left column and an image in the right? I want to set this h1 tag wide to all widths of both columns and over the image. Should I make it with CSS only, or here is another way specific to the block editor?

This image shows what I want.
[image]

P.S. According to comment below I specific what I wish. I want to learn how to write with JavaScript own reusable blocks.

Comment: When you talk about "development" of custom blocks are you asking how to create this layout in the editor, or do you want to use code to develop this as a custom block that other users can use? The former is more of a support question and better suited to the WordPress support forums, while the latter is very broad. The documentation on creating blocks is available here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/ As for the layout you'd use the same CSS & HTML that you'd use to make this layout outside of WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a combination of JavaScript for the custom block, and CSS to make the H1 span across both columns.

The JavaScript would be like this:

```
registerBlockType('my-plugin/two-columns', {
    title: 'Two Columns',
    icon: 'screenoptions',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string',
        },
        imageUrl: {
            type: 'string',
        },
    },
    edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
        const handleTitleChange = (title) => {
            setAttributes({ title });
        };

        const handleImageChange = (imageUrl) => {
            setAttributes({ imageUrl });
        };

        return (
            <div className="two-columns-block">
                <div className="two-columns-block-column two-columns-block-column-left">
                    <h1 className="two-columns-block-title">
                        <PlainText
                            value={attributes.title}
                            onChange={handleTitleChange}
                        />
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div className="two-columns-block-column two-columns-block-column-right">
                    <MediaUpload
                        onSelect={handleImageChange}
                        type="image"
                        value={attributes.imageUrl}
                        render={({ open }) => (
                            <Button className="button button-large" onClick={open}>
                                {!attributes.imageUrl ? 'Select Image' : 'Change Image'}
                            </Button>
                        )}
                    />
                    {attributes.imageUrl && (
                        <img src={attributes.imageUrl} alt="Image" />
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
    save({ attributes }) {
        return (
            <div className="two-columns-block">
                <div className="two-columns-block-column two-columns-block-column-left">
                    <h1 className="two-columns-block-title">{attributes.title}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="two-columns-block-column two-columns-block-column-right">
                    {attributes.imageUrl && (
                        <img src={attributes.imageUrl} alt="Image" />
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

This code defines a custom block called "Two Columns" that contains an `h1` tag in the left column and an image in the right column. The `edit` function is used to render the block in the block editor, and the `save` function is used to render the block in the frontend.

To make the `h1` tag look like it spans both columns, you can use the following CSS:

```
.two-columns-block {
    display: flex;
}

.two-columns-block-column {
    width: 50%;
}

.two-columns-block-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This CSS uses the `display: flex` property to make the container element a flex container. It sets the width of each column to 50%, which makes each column take up half the width of the container.

The `position: absolute` property is used to position the `h1` tag in the middle of the left column. The `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` properties are used to position the `h1` tag in the center of the column. The `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` property is used to move the `h1` tag up and to the left by half its width and height, which centers it in the column.

The `z-index: 1` property is used to make the `h1` tag appear on top of the image in the right column. This makes it look like the `h1` tag spans both columns.